# When I trying to download the pdf I cannot see in the screen, screen getting grey and nothing shown. How can I fix that?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to download PDF and show it on my screen, but it doesn't work, if I just call the PDF at the app startup (without being invoked by a touchable) it works fine.

These are the codes which I used

```
var articleList = [];
var currentMag = storageRef.child('issue 6 2.pdf');
var source = {uri:'https://www.orimi.com/pdf-test.pdf',cache:true};
```

```
constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {PDF: false};

        console.log('Current Mag: ' + currentMag);

        currentMag.getDownloadURL().then(function(url) {
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.responseType = 'blob';
            xhr.onload = function(event) {
                var blob = xhr.response;
                console.log('blob from xhr: ' + JSON.stringify(blob));
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = function() {
                    source.uri = reader.result;
                    this.setState(previousState => (
                        {PDF: !previousState.PDF}
                    ))
                }.bind(this);
                reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
            }.bind(this);
            xhr.open('GET', url);
            xhr.send();


        }.bind(this)).catch(function(error) {
            return (
                <View style={styles.container}>
                    <Text>Error: {error}</Text>
                </View>
            );
        });
    }
```

```
<PDFReader
                    source={source}
                    onLoadComplete={(numberOfPages,filePath)=>{
                        console.log('Number of pages: ${numberOfPages}');
                    }}
                    onPageChanged={(page,numberOfPages)=>{
                        console.log('Current page: ${page}');
                    }}
                    onError={(error)=>{
                        console.log('Error in rendering article: ' + error);
                    }}
                    style={styles.pdf}/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'`source`' is an object value. The module knows the object values and does not detach them. Please set a separate value.

> Requirements: Only `React-Native` 0.54+ support

```js
source={{uri: source.uri }}
```

OR you can use Webview

```js
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <WebView
          bounces={false}
          scrollEnabled={false} 
          source={{ uri: source.uri }} />
      </View>
...
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
  },
});
```

Comment: @Atakan And there is a duplicate 'https' in the address value. Remove it.

Comment: its not duplicated in my code I accidently copied two times in here and I edited. how can I delete the cache ?

Comment: @Atakan  Get rid of the cache syntax like my answer.

Comment: @Atakan  In the flag hub, it is said to be a module that can only be used in the Expo. This seems to be limited.

Comment: So, how can I fix that ? Is there any way to make this ?

Comment: @Atakan  You can use `Webview`